# How to remove new line character in a file without impact on the actual End of line in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, grep

*I am having issue with New line character in a file which originates from an external source.The new line character impact  is only for specific field @data5(shown below) and the application failing to read the format due to this.
Tried to remove it but its removing the actual End of the line as well.
Please let me know, how to remove new-line characters from in between a line without removing the new-line character from end of line.*
Data displayed as below

> data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5
>              ||data_6||data_7||data_8||data_9
>             data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5
>               ||data_6||data_7||data_8||data_9

Expected Output:
data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5||data_6||data_7||data_8||data_9
data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5||data_6||data_7||data_8||data_9

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do all alternate lines end with `data_5` as well does `data_5` start from 1st line number?

Comment: Yes, for all corrupted files alternate lines end with data_5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR%2{printf $0;next}1' yourfile
```

Add an extra step to ensure that the tricky line has the expected number of fields:

```
awk 'NR%2&&NF==9{printf $0;next}1' FS='|' yourfile
```

**Explanation**

`NR%2{printf $0;next}`: Avoids printing the carriage return just for the even lines, `next` avoids futher processing.

`1` : To print the odd lines normally.

Comment: The above command is working fine but it is also merging the data file which do not have any issue(Valid file). The code should not impact the valid file like the below: input: data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5||data_6||data_7||data‌​_8||data_9 data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5||data_6||data_7||data‌​_8||data_9  Output: data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5||data_6||data_7||data‌​_8||data_9 data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5||data_6||data_7||data‌​_8||data_9

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n\|\|/,"||")}1' file

data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5||data_6||data_7||data_8||data_9
data_1||data_2||data_3||data_4||data_5||data_6||data_7||data_8||data_9
```